# Does Accessor of datastax cassandra java driver use pagination?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Datastax's java driver for cassandra provides Accessor. Refer [here](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.1.7/features/object_mapper/using/#accessors)

With reference to their example as below, do they do pagination and fetch records in batches or is there a risk of the queries timing out ?

```
@Accessor
public interface UserAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    Result<User> getAll();
}
```

When I say pagination, do they internally do something similar to below

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM user");
stmt.setFetchSize(24);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a fetch size used behind the scenes. The driver will auto page for you as needed.

You will probably want to set a fetch size via [@QueryParameters](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/QueryParameters.html). The default at this time is 5k, see [DEFAULT_FETCH_SIZE](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.java#L40).

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Any idea what is the default fetch size behind the scenes if don't configure anything through @QueryParameters ?

Comment: Updated the answer with the current default and a link to the code where its set.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran is there anything else you are needing from the answer before accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I am using the fetchSize in the @QueryParameters annotation within an Accessor:

```
@Accessor
public interface UserAccessor {       

  @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
  @QueryParameters(fetchSize = 1000)
  Result<User> getAllUsers();
}
```